# ARM Assembly on using recv syscall

Tags: android, assembly, arm

I am starting to learn about ARM assembly from https://azeria-labs.com/writing-arm-shellcode/ and I want to practise receiving data from a socket. This is a code snippet of what I am learning so far. The testing is done on a mobile device.

Network client code

```
    @socket syscall
    movw r7,#281
    mov r0,#2
    mov r1,#1
    sub r2,r2,r2
    svc #1
    mov r6,r0

    @connect syscall
    movw r7,#283
    adr r1,struct
    strb r2,[r1,#1]
    mov r2,#16
    mov r0,r6
    svc #1

    @recv syscall
    mov r0,r6
    mov r3, #100
    adr r1,to_receive
    mov r2,#receive_size
    movw r7,#291
    svc #1

    @write syscall
    mov r7,#4
    mov r0,#1
    adr r1,to_receive
    mov r2,#receive_size
    svc #1

    @exit with error code from last syscall
    mov r7,#1
    svc #1

    struct:
    .ascii "\x02\xff" @AF_INET
    .ascii "\x11\x5c" @port 4444
    .byte 127,0,0,1   @ip 127.0.0.1

    to_receive: .skip 40
    after_to_receive:
    .set receive_size, after_to_receive - to_receive
```

At the other end of the network connection, I configured nc to listen and pipe some text data to a successful connection.

Network listener (server)

```
toybox nc -Lp 4444 < file_to_send.txt
```

However, I am not seeing any output to the client's console screen. I suspect that either the recv syscall is not receiving the data or that I am not using the write syscall correctly.

I don't see any error messages so I am not sure if I am doing it right. Any advice is appreciated.

I have separately confirmed that connecting another nc process to the listener will retrieve the text data.

Comment: Can you attach a debugger to this code and single-step it?  Or run `strace ./a.out` to trace the system calls it makes?  Developing asm without a debugger is like trying to build a robot blindfold - all you get is usually "doesn't work" or "crashes", without enough info to narrow down the cause.  Passing wrong args to system calls won't cause error messages unless you manually write error-handling code that makes `write` system calls to print error messages!  They just return `-EFAULT` if you pass a bad address, for example, not even raising SIGSEGV.

Comment: Hi @PeterCordes I forgot to add one line "movw r7, #291" to execute the syscall. After adding that and running the program in a debugger, I saw that recv syscall returns a non zero value "0x1a" which, according to the man pages, is the number of bytes received and I confirmed that the number of characters to send in the text file is indeed 26, including null byte.

But when I used the debugger to display the area in memory (the to_receive array/buffer?) using ````x/40x $pc```` I saw that its all zeroes with nothing filled in. So it seems like I am doing it wrong for using recv syscall?

Comment: Yes, that should be a byte count.  But `x/40x $pc` dumps the memory after the program counter, not the memory of the static buffer.  Use `x &to_receive` or `x $r1` or something.  But why `recv` instead of a simple `read()` from the socket, anyway?  And what flags does 100 (aka `0x64`) enable?  Also, your text file has a `0` byte?  That's weird.  Usually text files just end with a linefeed at the end of the last line.  Only when storing strings in an implicit-length C string in memory (not an explicit-length file) would you have a `0` byte.

Comment: Hi @PeterCordes

Yeah read syscall worked for me. I also realized that I gave the wrong flag value, coupled with the fact that I did not include the ````movw r7,#291```` before executing the recv syscall, which is probably why my code did not work in the first place.

Thanks for your help, at least now I know read() does work in similar ways as well.

Your suggestion is not an answer so I cannot mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: Half of the details needed to answer are in your comment, so you should [edit] your question.  But yeah, I'll post an answer if that solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a debugger (like GDB) and/or `strace ./a.out` to trace the system calls your program makes and figure out what's wrong.  It's normal for asm programs to either crash or silently do nothing, because bad args to a system call typically result in `-EFAULT`, `-EINVAL`, or `-ENOSYS`, not raising a SIGSEGV or anything like that.  But you won't know which or why unless you write error handling code or use `strace`.

(The OP reports that after doing this, it was obvious there was a missing `movw r7,#291` for the `recv` call number.)

---

(after fixing that mistake that debugging / tracing tools make obvious):

> using `x/40x $pc` I saw that its all zeroes with nothing filled in

`$pc` is the program counter, `r15`.  You want `x &to_receive` or `x $r1` or something to dump the memory in the static buffer you passed to `recv`.

Yes, the `0x1a` return value should be a byte count.

`flags=100` ( `0x64`) also seems weird, but there's no comment to explain which flags you want or why you're writing them in decimal.

**You don't even need `recv` in the first place**; you have a connected TCP socket and probably don't need any flags, so you can simply `read()` from the socket FD.